# Facebook SDK .Net - Error Authenticating, Calling App ID Does not match

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to implement Facebook authentication in my Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app.

Here is the Authentication code. AppID = Facebook App ID

```
public void Authenticate()
{
        Session fb = new Session(AppID);
        fb.LoginWithBehavior("public_profile,publish_actions,read_stream", FacebookLoginBehavior.LoginBehaviorApplicationOnly);
}
```

I can see the facebook app load and then flicks back to my app with the following error.

> {Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (Calling app's ID doesn't match the ID sent by the calling app - #2005) : Calling app's ID doesn't match the ID sent by the calling app
>      at Facebook.Client.AppAuthenticationHelper.ParseQueryString(AccessTokenData session, String queryString)
>      at MyRun.CustomUriMapper.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at MyRun.CustomUriMapper.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()}

I done the Facebook configuring as per [Configuring Windows Phone Silverlight apps](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/config/)

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer, was related to the Product ID.
For anyone else with the same issue, you have to ensure the Product ID matches in the following 4 places.

- Facebook app dev page
- Package.appxmanifest
- WMAppmanifest
- WMAppmanifest - (protocal extention)

NOTE: Doing the above will generally mean that you update your apps Product ID to using the one gerenated by the app store. By doing this you won't be able to debug your app on your phone if you have an installed version of the app. You will need to uninstall the app first.

Comment: Hi, sorry to add a comment now but I have an issue and I think is related to this Product ID. The thing is I don't know how to get the product ID, could you please tell me how I can get it ?